# Process builder strife - Syntax error. Missing '='

Tags: process-builder

new to process builder, trying to move from a formula field (which assigns a risk level, based on the values in three other fields) to a picklist, populated by process builder. (This is so I can then use consistent colours in Dashboard).
I've tried to copy the logic of the formula field, and update it to process builder-style fields, but getting the syntax error...

> The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Missing '='

this is my formula:

```
IF( ISPICKVAL( [In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Risk_present_MH__c  , "No" ) , "No risk" ,

IF( CASE( [In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Likelihood_mental_health__c  , "Very likely (5)", 5, "Likely (4)", 4, "Possible (3)", 3, "Slight (2)", 2, "Very unlikely (1)", 1, 0) * CASE( [In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Severity_of_impact_mental_health__c  , "Critical (5)", 5, "Major (4)", 4, "Significant (3)", 3, "Minor (2)", 2, "Insignificant (1)", 1, 0) < 8, "Low",

IF( CASE( [In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Likelihood_mental_health__c  , "Very likely (5)", 5, "Likely (4)", 4, "Possible (3)", 3, "Slight (2)", 2, "Very unlikely (1)", 1, 0) * CASE( [In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Severity_of_impact_mental_health__c  , "Critical (5)", 5, "Major (4)", 4, "Significant (3)", 3, "Minor (2)", 2, "Insignificant (1)", 1, 0) = 8, "Medium",

IF( CASE( [In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Likelihood_mental_health__c  , "Very likely (5)", 5, "Likely (4)", 4, "Possible (3)", 3, "Slight (2)", 2, "Very unlikely (1)", 1, 0) * CASE( [In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Severity_of_impact_mental_health__c  , "Critical (5)", 5, "Major (4)", 4, "Significant (3)", 3, "Minor (2)", 2, "Insignificant (1)", 1, 0) = 9, "Medium",

IF( CASE( [In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Likelihood_mental_health__c  , "Very likely (5)", 5, "Likely (4)", 4, "Possible (3)", 3, "Slight (2)", 2, "Very unlikely (1)", 1, 0) * CASE( [In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Severity_of_impact_mental_health__c  , "Critical (5)", 5, "Major (4)", 4, "Significant (3)", 3, "Minor (2)", 2, "Insignificant (1)", 1, 0) = 10, "Medium",

IF( CASE( [In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Likelihood_mental_health__c  , "Very likely (5)", 5, "Likely (4)", 4, "Possible (3)", 3, "Slight (2)", 2, "Very unlikely (1)", 1, 0) * CASE( [In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Severity_of_impact_mental_health__c  , "Critical (5)", 5, "Major (4)", 4, "Significant (3)", 3, "Minor (2)", 2, "Insignificant (1)", 1, 0) = 12, "Medium",

IF( CASE([In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Likelihood_mental_health__c   , "Very likely (5)", 5, "Likely (4)", 4, "Possible (3)", 3, "Slight (2)", 2, "Very unlikely (1)", 1, 0) * CASE( [In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Severity_of_impact_mental_health__c  , "Critical (5)", 5, "Major (4)", 4, "Significant (3)", 3, "Minor (2)", 2, "Insignificant (1)", 1, 0) > 12, "High", "" )))))))
```

Comment: Just a general suggestion - before save flows are well suited to this type of work, and are much faster than process builder.  To resolve the syntax issues, I suggest you start with a single scenario, and the add to it.

Answer (score 1):

From line 3 to 6 where you are checking if the values are equal to a number, there should be two equals instead of one.

Try this

```
IF( ISPICKVAL( [In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Risk_present_MH__c  , "No" ) , "No risk" ,

IF( CASE( [In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Likelihood_mental_health__c  , "Very likely (5)", 5, "Likely (4)", 4, "Possible (3)", 3, "Slight (2)", 2, "Very unlikely (1)", 1, 0) * CASE( [In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Severity_of_impact_mental_health__c  , "Critical (5)", 5, "Major (4)", 4, "Significant (3)", 3, "Minor (2)", 2, "Insignificant (1)", 1, 0) < 8, "Low",

IF( CASE( [In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Likelihood_mental_health__c  , "Very likely (5)", 5, "Likely (4)", 4, "Possible (3)", 3, "Slight (2)", 2, "Very unlikely (1)", 1, 0) * CASE( [In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Severity_of_impact_mental_health__c  , "Critical (5)", 5, "Major (4)", 4, "Significant (3)", 3, "Minor (2)", 2, "Insignificant (1)", 1, 0) == 8, "Medium",

IF( CASE( [In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Likelihood_mental_health__c  , "Very likely (5)", 5, "Likely (4)", 4, "Possible (3)", 3, "Slight (2)", 2, "Very unlikely (1)", 1, 0) * CASE( [In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Severity_of_impact_mental_health__c  , "Critical (5)", 5, "Major (4)", 4, "Significant (3)", 3, "Minor (2)", 2, "Insignificant (1)", 1, 0) == 9, "Medium",

IF( CASE( [In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Likelihood_mental_health__c  , "Very likely (5)", 5, "Likely (4)", 4, "Possible (3)", 3, "Slight (2)", 2, "Very unlikely (1)", 1, 0) * CASE( [In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Severity_of_impact_mental_health__c  , "Critical (5)", 5, "Major (4)", 4, "Significant (3)", 3, "Minor (2)", 2, "Insignificant (1)", 1, 0) == 10, "Medium",

IF( CASE( [In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Likelihood_mental_health__c  , "Very likely (5)", 5, "Likely (4)", 4, "Possible (3)", 3, "Slight (2)", 2, "Very unlikely (1)", 1, 0) * CASE( [In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Severity_of_impact_mental_health__c  , "Critical (5)", 5, "Major (4)", 4, "Significant (3)", 3, "Minor (2)", 2, "Insignificant (1)", 1, 0) == 12, "Medium",

IF( CASE([In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Likelihood_mental_health__c   , "Very likely (5)", 5, "Likely (4)", 4, "Possible (3)", 3, "Slight (2)", 2, "Very unlikely (1)", 1, 0) * CASE( [In_Form__Risk_Assessment__c].Severity_of_impact_mental_health__c  , "Critical (5)", 5, "Major (4)", 4, "Significant (3)", 3, "Minor (2)", 2, "Insignificant (1)", 1, 0) > 12, "High", "" )))))))
```